# ES-v5.0.1 throw java.lang.SecurityException while snapshot

Tags: java, hadoop, elasticsearch-plugin, securityexception

**Elasticsearch version**:v5.0.1

**Plugins installed**: [repository-hdfs]

**JVM version**:
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

**OS version**:
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
Linux version 2.6.32-573.26.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed May 4 00:57:44 UTC 2016

**Description of the problem including expected versus actual behavior**:

When I create repositories, ES response 
"{
  "acknowledged": true
}",
but when I create snapshot of index, it throws exception:

```
[2016-12-12T11:38:04,417][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] path: /_snapshot/my_hdfs_repo/20161209-snapshot, params: {repository=my_hdfs_repo, snapshot=20161209-snapshot}
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [node-2][10.90.6.234:9340][cluster:admin/snapshot/create]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoryException: [my_hdfs_repo] could not read repository data from index blob
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.getRepositoryData(BlobStoreRepository.java:751) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.snapshots.SnapshotsService.createSnapshot(SnapshotsService.java:226) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.snapshots.create.TransportCreateSnapshotAction.masterOperation(TransportCreateSnapshotAction.java:82) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.snapshots.create.TransportCreateSnapshotAction.masterOperation(TransportCreateSnapshotAction.java:41) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.masterOperation(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$3.doRun(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:520) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.security.auth.PrivateCredentialPermission" "org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials" "read")
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufHelper.getRemoteException(ProtobufHelper.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:580) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getListing(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:2094) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:2077) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.listStatus(Hdfs.java:254) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1798) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1794) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1800) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1759) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1718) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobContainer$6.run(HdfsBlobContainer.java:145) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobContainer$6.run(HdfsBlobContainer.java:142) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobStore$4.run(HdfsBlobStore.java:136) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:713) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobStore.execute(HdfsBlobStore.java:133) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobContainer.listBlobsByPrefix(HdfsBlobContainer.java:142) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.listBlobsToGetLatestIndexId(BlobStoreRepository.java:849) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.latestIndexBlobId(BlobStoreRepository.java:818) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.getRepositoryData(BlobStoreRepository.java:721) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.snapshots.SnapshotsService.createSnapshot(SnapshotsService.java:226) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.snapshots.create.TransportCreateSnapshotAction.masterOperation(TransportCreateSnapshotAction.java:82) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.snapshots.create.TransportCreateSnapshotAction.masterOperation(TransportCreateSnapshotAction.java:41) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.masterOperation(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$3.doRun(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:520) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.NotSerializableExceptionWrapper: service_exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.security.auth.PrivateCredentialPermission" "org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials" "read")
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:243) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getListing(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:573) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getListing(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:2094) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:2077) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.listStatus(Hdfs.java:254) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1798) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1794) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1800) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1759) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1718) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobContainer$6.run(HdfsBlobContainer.java:145) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobContainer$6.run(HdfsBlobContainer.java:142) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobStore$4.run(HdfsBlobStore.java:136) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:713) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobStore.execute(HdfsBlobStore.java:133) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobContainer.listBlobsByPrefix(HdfsBlobContainer.java:142) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.listBlobsToGetLatestIndexId(BlobStoreRepository.java:849) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.latestIndexBlobId(BlobStoreRepository.java:818) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.getRepositoryData(BlobStoreRepository.java:721) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.snapshots.SnapshotsService.createSnapshot(SnapshotsService.java:226) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.snapshots.create.TransportCreateSnapshotAction.masterOperation(TransportCreateSnapshotAction.java:82) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.snapshots.create.TransportCreateSnapshotAction.masterOperation(TransportCreateSnapshotAction.java:41) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.masterOperation(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$3.doRun(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:520) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: access denied ("javax.security.auth.PrivateCredentialPermission" "org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials" "read")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission2(AccessControlContext.java:538) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject$ClassSet.populateSet(Subject.java:1414) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject$ClassSet.<init>(Subject.java:1372) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.getPrivateCredentials(Subject.java:767) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCredentialsInternal(UserGroupInformation.java:1499) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getTokens(UserGroupInformation.java:1464) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.<init>(Client.java:436) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1519) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1446) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getListing(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:573) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getListing(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:2094) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:2077) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.listStatus(Hdfs.java:254) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1798) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1794) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1800) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1759) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1718) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobContainer$6.run(HdfsBlobContainer.java:145) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobContainer$6.run(HdfsBlobContainer.java:142) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobStore$4.run(HdfsBlobStore.java:136) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:713) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobStore.execute(HdfsBlobStore.java:133) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.hdfs.HdfsBlobContainer.listBlobsByPrefix(HdfsBlobContainer.java:142) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.listBlobsToGetLatestIndexId(BlobStoreRepository.java:849) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.latestIndexBlobId(BlobStoreRepository.java:818) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.getRepositoryData(BlobStoreRepository.java:721) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.snapshots.SnapshotsService.createSnapshot(SnapshotsService.java:226) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.snapshots.create.TransportCreateSnapshotAction.masterOperation(TransportCreateSnapshotAction.java:82) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.snapshots.create.TransportCreateSnapshotAction.masterOperation(TransportCreateSnapshotAction.java:41) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.masterOperation(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$3.doRun(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:520) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
```

**Steps to reproduce**:

1.create repositories

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup
{
"type": "hdfs",
"settings": {
      "path": "/path/on/hadoop",
      "uri": "hdfs://hadoop_cluster_domain:[port]",
      "conf_location":"/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml,/hadoop/core-site.xml",
      "user":"hadoop"
    }
}
```

2.snapshot my index

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true
```

3.exception is throwed

Comment: i have the same issue... a configuration problem with the java security manager?

Comment: I have opened an issue in github: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22156

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Change the default java security policy of the HDFS plugin.

The policy file is located at `ES_HOME/plugins/repository-hdfs/plugin-security.policy`, where `ES_HOME` is your installation path of Elasticsearch. Add the following policy:

```java
grant {
    // ... existing policies
    permission javax.security.auth.PrivateCredentialPermission "org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials * \"*\"", "read";
}
```

Then, in the start script of Elasticsearch (`ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch`), add the following Java option to the command line arguments:

```sh
-Djava.security.policy=ES_HOME/plugins/repository-hdfs/plugin-security.policy
```

Synchronize the modified files to all cluster nodes.
Finally, restart all cluster nodes.

**Reference**

1. [[ElasticSearch填坑] 创建Snapshot: SecurityException](https://www.jianshu.com/p/f14f0afed345)